# C++ preserve indexes for next iteration?

Tags: c++

I have a loop in which I want to preserve values for next iteration. I decided to use `std::vector` for that (although I don't know if it is the best way) but when I check `if(bottomMap[i] == true)` it doesn't compile.

```
vector<bool> bottomMap;
for (int i = 0; i < str.size() ; i++){
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
        cout << "XXXX";
    } else {
           if (bottomMap[i] == true)
            cout << "YYYY";
        else
            cout << "X";
        }
    }
    vector <bool> bottomMap(topMap);
}
```

Comment: `bottomMap` is used before its declaration.

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: I declare it before loop too.

Comment: you have to define the variable before you use it, which is clearkly not the case here. Furthermore, since you want to preserve the values between iterations, you should define the vector outside the foor loop body - in this case outside the loop itself.

Comment: Actually it compiles, but than it doesn't print anything :(

Comment: *I declare it before loop too.* No you don't, at least not in the code you are showing us. And since crystal balls don't work in this world, please show us your real code ;-)

Comment: We deal with real code. `bottomMap` is declared before the loop and in the loop.

Comment: Ok, yes it was my mistake, i didn't show everything because i thought it's not main problem. However, nobody said the same for topMap vector. It doesn't have visible declaration too :)

Answer (score 1):

bottomMap have to exist BEFORE the loop begins

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size() ; i++){
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
        cout << "XXXX";
    } else {
           if (bottomMap[i] == true) //< ERROR: bootomMap here is not declred.
            cout << "YYYY";
        else
            cout << "X";
        }
    }
    vector <bool> bottomMap(topMap); //< Declared here, but destroyed to the very next '}'
}
```

Try this

```
vector <bool> bottomMap(topMap);   //< MOVED HERE
for (int i = 0; i < str.size() ; i++){
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
        cout << "XXXX";
    } else {
           if (bottomMap[i] == true)
            cout << "YYYY";
        else
            cout << "X";
        }
    }
                                  ///< AND NOMORE HERE
}
```

Suggetsion: keep open and close brace aligned: it will cost some more line, be will be easy for you to find when things begin and end their existence

This is your code, realigned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size() ; i++)
{
    if (str[i] != ' ')  
    {
        cout << "XXXX";
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (bottomMap[i] == true) //< ERROR: bottomMap here is not declared.
            cout << "YYYY";
        else
            cout << "X";
    }
}
vector <bool> bottomMap(topMap); //< Declared here, but too late!
} //< ERROR: TOO CLOSED BRACES
```

Comment: topMap vector is also not defined in the part of code that i posted, bottomMap is as well defined before the loop, but unfortunately that didn't change my problem. I made a mistake, actually it compiles but it doesn't print anything when i add that condition if (bottomMap[i] == true)

Comment: At least, i learned something about code styling. Thank you Emilio

Comment: *topMap vector is also not defined in the part of code that i posted*:yes, I assumed it is somewhere before, but ... *bottomMap is as well defined before the loop*: well, if this is the case, it cannot be redefined later (unless it is in another outer scope, but the new one will hide the previous). This is incongruent whatever it is declared before or not.

Comment: We can say nothing about what branches the program run through, because we have no idea about the values the variables carry.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the place where you use `bottommap` it has no idea of its definition.  You have to define it before you use it.

Comment: I declared it before the loop.